# Qu'a l'accent français de si caractéristique ?

Tags: prononciation, comparaison-de-langues

Je suis en Suède depuis maintenant quelques semaines, et je m'exprime beaucoup en anglais, faute de savoir déjà parler suédois.

Je suis toutefois très surpris de constater que la plupart de mes interlocuteurs arrivent souvent très rapidement à deviner mes origines françaises, quel que soit leur pays d'origine (les autres *exchange students* par exemple).

Typiquement, un jour un suédois nous a proposé de deviner nos pays d'origine par nos accents quand nous parlions anglais, et il avait beaucoup moins de mal à reconnaître l'accent français parmi les autres accents (et il ne parlait pas français).

Existe-t-il vraiment quelque chose qui rendrait l'« accent français » si typique et facile à reconnaître, ou bien a-t-il simplement fait usage des statistiques ?
 Il y a apparemment beaucoup de français qui partent faire leurs études en Suède, et il aurait simplement pu se dire qu'il y avait plus de chance de tomber juste en misant sur le français, plutôt que sur une autre langue.

Comment: Les comparaisons entre langues sont du ressort de linguistics.stackexchange.com où on a plus de chance de trouver des réponses appropriées.

Comment: Il n'y a pas que l'accent, il y a aussi la facon de se comporter et de s'habiller. Habitant en Allemagne, et parlant avec un accent vraiment léger, j'ai mis deux ans avant que les Allemands ne reconnaissent plus mon accent francais à la première phrase voire au premier mot (ils reconnaissent encore que je suis étranger). À l'aéroport de Bâle (en revenant d'Allemagne), les douaniers me parlaient en Francais avant que je ne montre mon passeport (ils sont très forts) ou au plus tard après le premier "Guten Tag", "Buongiorno" ou "Hello" (j'ai tout essayé).

Comment: Voir aussi [ceci](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/112384/16335) pour illustrer une perspective différente, avec certaines informations supplémentaires...

Comment: La non-aspiration des consonnes sourdes et le ʁ sont des marqueurs communs au français et à l'allemand. Les assimilations de voisement sont progressive en allemand (caricature : absent [abzɑ̃]) et régressive en français (absent [apsɑ̃]). Il y a bien d'autres caractéristiques audibles sur les voyelles...

Comment: La réponse de GAM PUB est tellement intéressante, que je souhaiterais que ce soit une réponse développée!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En plus de la prononciation des ***th*** et des ***r*** et du mauvais placement de l'accent tonique, l'accent français se caractérise souvent aussi par:

- la non distinction des voyelles longues: (*beach*/*bitch*, *sheet*/*shit*).
- l'instabilité de la prononciation de la consonne ***h*** (indifférenciation entre *heat*, *hit*, *it* et *eat*)
- la non diphtongaison de voyelles (*plane* prononcé /plene/ au lieu de /pleyne/, *paste* prononcé *pest*, ...)

Comment: Bonne réponse, même si les exemples choisis pour les voyelles longues/courtes sont un peu... grossiers, au sens propre du terme ? :-)

Comment: @Spadon_ soigneusement choisis, c'est vrai ! ;-)

Comment: Et les diphtongs sont differents: *point* (fr) vs *point* (en), par ex. Il y a un cuisinier francais celebre aux US (depuis des decennies) qui prononce toujours *point* en anglais comme s'il parlait francais.

Comment: @Drew Indeed, I suspect some famous people to keep their accent stronger than it should on purpose as it is part of their character. There is a famous British singer/actress who has probably spent most of her time in France for the last 45 years but has kept her original accent almost unchanged and is still confusing many French word genders.

Comment: Egalement, les Français utilisent beaucoup l'article _the_ là où les anglophones ne mettent pas d'article.

Comment: @BrunoBonnefont ce n'est plus tout à fait du domaine de l'accent.

Comment: @jiliagre One good such example is former French President Chirac, who spoke English with a heavy French accent when on camera. I suspect he actually spoke much better in private. There are some videos where he is caught "off guard" and speaks much better than usually.

Comment: Et sinon les Francais ont tendance a placer des mots francais dans la phrase quand ils ne connaissent pas un terme. Il y a peu d'Européens qui font ca à part les Francais.

Comment: @Yves, On ne peut pas parler d'accent français dans ce cas mais d'une caractéristique de l'anglais tel qu'il est parlé par les français. D'autre part, la probabilité qu'un mot français existe aussi tel quel en anglais est certainement beaucoup plus élevée que pour quelque autre langue européenne, ceci explique cela.

Comment: Oui c'est vrai mais c'est très typique. Sinon il y a aussi la prononciation typiquement francaise des voyelles, au delà de la non-distinction court/long. On voit par exemple rarement un francais prononcer "bus" /ˈbʌs/ mais plutot /ˈbəs/.

Answer (score 2):

En général, ce qui nous trahit (les Français) quand on parle anglais, c'est le "th" prononcé "z", le "r" mal prononcé, et aussi la mélodie qui est caractéristique du français (càd assez monotone).

Pour le coup, la mélodie est aussi caractéristique de beaucoup d'autres langues, tu trouveras très facile de reconnaître un italophone ou un hispanophone à la mélodie qu'il utilise en anglais. Et tu verras assez rapidement que les Suédois (même s'ils parlent très très bien anglais) ont une mélodie très reconnaissable eux aussi!

Et accessoirement, bienvenue en Suède!

Comment: La mélodie n'est pas monotone, mais plutôt que d'apparaitre à l'intérieur des mots elle se forme sur les groupes de mots.

Comment: Mouais, comparé à de l'espagnol ou de l'italien, le français reste beaucoup moins chantant...

Comment: C'est parce que le français n'a pas un accent tonique aussi marqué, et cela d'autant plus qu'il est très régulier, toujours sur la dernière syllable du groupe syntactique.

Fait amusant: the th->z est extrêmement typique des francophones *européens*. Les Québécois disent généralement /d/ pour ce son.

Answer (score 2):

Au delà de la prononciation, de l'accentuation, de la mélodie des phrases et de la respiration, (je pense à l'expiration, un peu caricaturée par [Amy Walker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tw89DzP4RTs&index=2&list=PLkvBxZ4952-_w90k1ZsK3SBM5aaslULAE)), il y a quelque chose qui trahit les Français de façon visuelle.

Selon mon expérience, les Français ont tendance à n'impliquer que le bout des lèvres dans leur manière de parler. En simplifiant, je remarque qu'on peut très bien parler Français "dans sa barbe", sans articulation aucune et sans même décoller les dents. C'est comme si tout se passait dans un bec.

À l'inverse, les Anglo-saxons impliqueront beaucoup plus la mâchoire, la bouche s'ouvrira plus grand, et manqueront de nuances dans le mouvement et la forme des lèvres.

Si bien que pour parler Anglais (ou toute autre langue), il peut être utile de singer les grimaces d'un Anglo-saxon. J'ajouterai que c'est même une piste pour reconnaître dans la rue quelqu'un qui parle Anglais sans l'entendre. Même remarque pour un Français.

Answer (score 2):

Much of what constitutes a French accent seems to me the fact that French can simply do away with stress (tonic) accent. To an A-S speaker it sounds as if all the 'words' are being run together. As a young linguistics student many years ago, I heard French phonology compared to that of Inuit, a super agglutinative tongue. Given also the high degree of homophony in French, the English speaker sometimes has to hear the entire phrase uttered in French before being sure of its meaning. I remember being faintly pleased when I heard someone say: "Je ne sais pas à quel sein me vouer". Right or left!?

Comment: That last expression is indeed confusing, especially since people stopped saying, "[Je ne sais pas à quel *saint* me vouer](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/ne%20pas%20savoir%20%C3%A0%20quel%20saint%20se%20vouer)". :-P

Comment: It's the reason why people who learn French, always think that French talk fast, when it's not the case. You answer is extremely interesting.

Comment: @user800 C'est encore utilisé.